# Synchronizing both PIO clock dividers in the Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: pi-pico

I want to run the same SM (state machine) program on all 8 available SM in the RP2040, but I ran into a small problem trying to get them to run exactly synchronized while using the clock divider.

This is easy when you only use *one* PIO: `pio_enable_sm_mask_in_sync()`. The problem is that you can't do this for both PIO:

```
pio_enable_sm_mask_in_sync(pio0,0xF);
pio_enable_sm_mask_in_sync(pio1,0xF);
```

Even if there is only one machine cycle between these calls, PIO0 will start ticking before PIO1.

I can have them wait for an event:

```
wait 1 gpio 21
set pins 1
```

If this code is loaded on every SM in both PIOs, each SM having a unique pin mapping, I would like to see this:

```
         GPIO21 _____/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM0 GPIO01 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM1 GPIO02 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM2 GPIO03 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM3 GPIO04 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO1 SM0 GPIO05 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO1 SM1 GPIO06 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO1 SM2 GPIO07 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO1 SM3 GPIO08 _________/‾‾‾‾
```

However, with the clock divider enabled, I think I will see something like this:

```
         GPIO21 _____/‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM0 GPIO01 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM1 GPIO02 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM2 GPIO03 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO0 SM3 GPIO04 _________/‾‾‾‾
PIO1 SM0 GPIO05 __________/‾‾‾
PIO1 SM1 GPIO06 __________/‾‾‾
PIO1 SM2 GPIO07 __________/‾‾‾
PIO1 SM3 GPIO08 __________/‾‾‾
```

That is, even if they start at the same time, the clock divider's phase will be slightly different between each PIO.

Can someone think of a way to solve this?